# How to convert JSONObject to JSONArray in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have request something like this.

```
{"REQ_DATA":
    {"CLPH_NO":"010123456789","USE_INTT_NO":""}
}
```

but server accepts only this

```
{"REQ_DATA":
    [{"CLPH_NO":"010123456789","USE_INTT_NO":""}]
}
```

What should I do? I quite noob about JSON, please help me.

Comment: What have you tried? What does not work? What android programming language are you using? Are you using Embarcadero or Android Studio? Different Dialects etc...

Comment: Have you fixed `onGtinNetworkResponse` error ? And didn't you even find my ans a little bit helpful though it was fully dynamic ?

Comment: Please don't down vote me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REQ_DATA needs to be a JSONArray. Try implementing something like this

```
        try {

          JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
          JSONArray requiredDataArray = new JSONArray();
          JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
          data.put("CLPH_NO", "010123456789");
          data.put("USE_INTT_NO", "");
          requiredDataArray.put(data);
          object.put("REQ_DATA", requiredDataArray);
          Log.d("JSON", object.toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I still got this error like this: 

onGtinNetworkResponse jsonOutput::{"RSLT_CD":"A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of "}

Do you know the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```java
JSONObject fromRequest = request.getJSONObject();// given from request
JSONObject toServer = new JSONObject();
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
arr.put(fromRequest.get("REQ_DATA"));
toServer.put("REQ_DATA", arr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I still got this error like this: 

onGtinNetworkResponse jsonOutput::{"RSLT_CD":"A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of "}

Do you know the problem?

Comment: does the server accept a `JSONObject` or a json string? If it is the latter, you have to call `toServer.toString()`. Can you please post the code to send the request to the server?

Comment: Sorry, I fix it now. The problem wasn't on my code. It's server side. I"m so sorry for inconvenient.

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't *change* a JSONObject to a JSONArray, rather, you create a JSONArray and then add the JSONObject to that array.

```
try {
    JSONObject reqData = new JSONObject();
    reqData.put("CLPH_NO", "010123456789");
    reqData.put("USE_INTT_NO", "");

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    array.put(reqData);
    JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
    request.put("REQ_DATA", reqData);

    String requestAsJSONString = request.toString();

    // call web service

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

You need to send `requestAsJSONString` to the server.

Furthermore, I suggest you put the JSON object keys in final fields, like so:

```
static final String KEY_REQ_DATA = "REQ_DATA";
```

and then use `KEY_REQ_DATA` in your code instead of using the hardcoded String.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I still got this error like this: 

onGtinNetworkResponse jsonOutput::{"RSLT_CD":"A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of "}

Do you know the problem?

Comment: Would you mind showing how you are actually sending it to the server?

Comment: Sorry, I fix it now. The problem wasn't on my code. It's server side. I"m so sorry for inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

```
Jsonarray array = new Jsonarray();
Jsonobject insidearray = new jsonobject;

insidearray.put("CLPH_NO", "010123456789");
insidearray.put("USE_INTT_NO", "");

array.put(insidearray);

Jsonobject object = new Jsonobject();

object.put("REQ_DATA",array);
```

The variables may need a little editing, doing this from a phone but there you go

Answer (score 1):

**Just simple solution without using any hard-coded Strings**

```
JSONObject currentJson = new JSONObject(yourJsonString); //Your current jsonObject
JSONObject newJsonObject = new JSONObject(); //new jsonObject you want to send to server
newJsonObject.put(currentJson.keys().next().toString(),
           new JSONArray().put(currentJson.getString(currentJson.keys().next().toString())));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple solution for your json string as per server check it

```
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();

    try {
        jo.put("CLPH_NO", "010123456789");
        jo.put("USE_INTT_NO", "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    ja.put(jo);

    JSONObject final_jo = new JSONObject();

    try {
        final_jo.put("REQ_DATA", ja);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),final_jo.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```